# Point particle and angular deficit

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, singularities, point-particles

I would like to understand in what sense an angular deficit can be interpreted as a point particle. Typically, if you have a metric in polar coordinates such as:
$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + a^2(t,r) dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2$$
If you do not impose that $a(t,0) = 1$, then you get an angle deficit (or surplus depending on whether $a(t,0) is > or < 1$) at $r=0$.
Now, I get the intuitive picture, about how geometrically, this is like a cone, with a (conical) singularity at $r=0$, but mathematically how does that describe a particle? Normally, particles would come about from the stress tensor by using delta functions, but there is no such consideration here though?

Comment: having metric, you can compute using einsteins equations what kind of stress tensor would produce it.

Comment: Calculate the metric for a disk of constant density, and shrink the the radius of the disk while keeping its mass constant...